# why is the cleavage in frogs holoblastic and not meroblastic?

Tags: embryology, development

**background information** 
The cleavage of the frog embryo during the embryo development is holoblastic (complete cleavage). However when we look at yolk-rich eggs we see a cleavage pattern which is meroblastic (partial cleavage).

**Question**
But the frog eggs are also yolk rich right? So why do frog embryo's use holoblastic cleavage?

Answer (score 1):

Because:

1. Frog eggs are not yolk-rich. They are mesolecithal, they have an intermediate amount of yolk.
2. Yolk is concentrated within vegetal pole of the egg. That is why yolk-packed macromeres divide much slower than micromeres on the vegetal pole, which barely contain any yolk.
   [image: Amphibians cleavage]

My sources:

- https://kjcscientific.wordpress.com/project-excalibur/
- Gilbert's Developmental Biology (2009)